# Why does SSA/ASS not accept timecodes larger than 9:59:59.99

Tags: subtitle, srt

I have a SRT file which contain timecodes > 100 hours (e.g. 123:45:67.891; hhh:mm:ss:fff). Now I stumpled upon this issue when converting my SRT to ASS using ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i subs.srt styled.ass
```

In the ASS file, all the timecodes in the SRT that are equal/bigger than 10:00:00.00 were changed to 9:59:59.99. First thought ffmpeg was doing something strange, but I read that the format for ASS is `h:mm:ss.ff`. Now I'm wondering why is this?   Why doesnt it support `hh:mm:ss.fff` like SRT does?

Comment: Are you watching *many* videos longer than ten hours? As far as I'm aware, only certain German opera inflict this level of pain on people :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo haha, well it's just that the file is +/- 140 hours long in total (128GB). I thought styling the subtitles a bit would be a nice touch, but thats not going to happen. Ofcourse I could do something like breaking the complete file into 14 pieces, hardcode the subtitles and then concatentate the pieces back together again, but that would just be too much of a pain in the ass. I'm just wondering why it doesnt accept >10 hours (cant really seem to find any clarification on why its limited like this).